# Updated Libre Barcode 128 google font doesn't load in to canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have to load Libre Barcode 128 font family in to fabric canvas. But Barcode doesn't view on canvas. How to set Libre Barcode 128 font family in fabric js canvas?

```js
var text;
var canvas;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  setTimeout(function() {
    text = new fabric.Text("Text", {
      fontSize: 70,
      left: 100,
      top: 0,
      fill: '#sew3435'
    });
    canvas.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", 'Libre Barcode 128');
    canvas.renderAll();
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Text" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <style>
      .ss {
        font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39 Text';
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ss">Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
    <canvas id="c" width=500 height=250></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share whatever code you already have so that we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: See my updated code @JensS

Answer (score 1):

The actual font is a 3-of-9 font, not 128 (though they are treated the same way) and the name should be (as defined in the CSS):

```
.set("fontFamily", "'Libre Barcode 39 Text'");
```

You might have to "preuse" the font on an DOM element before it will be picked up by the canvas.

Update: seems as FabricJS uses incoming string as-is so the inner quotes must be added also there due to the spaces in the font family name (included here for completeness).

**[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/rtg1kc97/)**

Comment: Please refer this fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/Kz7VL/39/

I used Libre Barcode 39 Text font family in Fabric js, but its not working @K3N

Comment: @NandhiKumar ah yeah, seems as FabricJS doesn't apply quotes internally for names with spaces in it. Added that point for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text;
  var canvas;
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  setTimeout(function() {
  text = new fabric.Text("Text", {
  fontSize: 70,
  left: 100,
  top: 0,
  fill: '#f00'
  });
  canvas.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
  canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", "'Libre Barcode 39 Text'");
  canvas.renderAll();
  }, 500)
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Text" 
rel="stylesheet">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="c" width=500 height=250></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

We have to set font family name with in single quotes like " 'Libre Barcode 39 Text' ", Finally it works for me.